# Task manager always crashes within a few seconds

Tags: windows-7, windows, crash, task-manager

This is the error report:

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH  
Application Name: taskmgr.exe  
Application Version: 6.1.7600.16385  
Application Timestamp: 4a5bc3ee  
Fault Module Name: hostv32.dll  
Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0  
Fault Module Timestamp: 4c5c027d  
Exception Code: c0000005  
Exception Offset: 0000000000068b73  
OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48  
Locale ID: 1033  
Additional Information 1: bf4f  
Additional Information 2: bf4f79e8ecbde38b818b2c0e2771a379  
Additional Information 3: d246  
Additional Information 4: d2464c78aa97e6b203cd0fca121f9a58  

Read our privacy statement online:  
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409  

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our 
privacy statement offline: 
C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Whenever I open the task manager, within a few seconds it crashes, saying it has stopped working with the above report.

I took the fault module (hostv32.dll) and scanned it with avast but it found no threat.  I also ran a SFC /scannow from an elevated command prompt and it didn't find any corrupted files.  This problem is in all two user accounts in this computer (Windows 7). Any reason/solution to this problem?

Comment: Avast isn't a very good scanner IMO. Try scanning it with [40 other scanners](http://virustotal.com). (That sounded too much like a Russian software ad.)

Comment: Does the same happen in safe mode?

Comment: I'm going with you have a mean rootkit that does in memory patching or redirections of syscalls and it's causing taskmanger to puke.  Boot from live media and scan from there(with better AV).

Comment: the only thing i got from virustotal was:

Comment: VIPRE 7942 2011.01.03 PC Pandora (fs).. everything other antivirus didn't turn up anything

Comment: This question has been repeated at http://superuser.com/questions/228734/task-manager-always-crashes

Answer (score 1):

I had this error after disabling the "Performance Counters for Windows" device driver (assuming it got disabled on your machine and that this isn't some other issue).

To reenable: from the Start Menu, right click on "Computer", click "Manage", and then click "Device Manager" in the left column. Click the "View" menu at the top, and select "Show hidden devices", then click the "Non-Plug and Play Drivers" category to expand it. Find the "Performance Counters for Windows Driver" entry, double click it, select the "Driver" tab, and change the "Startup Type" to "Boot". Click the "Start" button, then click "OK" and start Task Manager again. Reboot if it still doesn't work.

If the service is already started, or these steps don't fix the problem, you have a different issue. I realize the OP is long gone, but hopefully this answer will be helpful to others like me who run into this issue and can't find anything via Google.