# Task Manager always crashes

Tags: windows-7, windows, crash, task-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Task manager always crashes within a few seconds](https://superuser.com/questions/228426/task-manager-always-crashes-within-a-few-seconds)

This is the error report:

Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name: taskmgr.exe
Application Version: 6.1.7600.16385
Application Timestamp: 4a5bc3ee
Fault Module Name: hostv32.dll
Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
Fault Module Timestamp: 4c5c027d
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Offset: 0000000000068b73
OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48
Locale ID: 1033
Additional Information 1: bf4f
Additional Information 2: bf4f79e8ecbde38b818b2c0e2771a379
Additional Information 3: d246
Additional Information 4: d2464c78aa97e6b203cd0fca121f9a58

Read our privacy statement online:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our 
privacy statement offline: 
C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

Whenever I open the task manager, within a few seconds it crashes, saying it has stopped working with the above report.

I took the fault module (hostv32.dll) and scanned it with avast but it found no threat. I also ran a SFC /scannow from an elevated command prompt and it didn't find any corrupted files. This problem is in all two user accounts in this computer (Windows 7). There was one time where task manager seemed to work, but when I closed it and opened it again, it crashed.  Any reason/solution to this problem?

Comment: Run a chkdsk on the hard drive.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/228426/task-manager-always-crashes-within-a-few-seconds. It would be better if you would delete one of them. You can always edit your question if new information becomes available.

Comment: I've voted to close this as an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying running the system filechecker;

```
sfc /scannow
```

This should rebuild the file automatically :)